# multiple string functions in one line

Tags: python, string

I know how to solve this problem using multiple lines but in the spirit of clean code is there a way to run multiple string functions in the same line?

Essentially I'm returning a string using

```
''.join(string.title())
```

after I need to remove whitespaces from the new modified string:

```
string.replace(" ", '')
```

The whitespace is important at the beginning as it allows me to use the title function so the order shouldn't change.

Comment: Just do `''.join(string.title()).replace(" ","")`

Comment: What does `''.join(string.title())` do that `string.title()` doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add together string functions like this:

`''.join(string.title()).replace(" ", '')`

Hope this helps you.